# Gerunds vs Participles

Tags: grammar, british-english, gerunds, participles, present-participles

'Hearing the sound, they came out of the house'. In this sentence what is the part of speech of 'hearing'. In my opinion it is present participle but my book says it is gerund. Can anyone explain me how to differentiate between the two? All I know is that in "V1+ing + noun" format, it is a present participle if the noun is the doer of that action(e.g. running deer) otherwise not.

Comment: Present participle. Participle used to be a part of speech before adjectives were discovered. It is certainly not a gerund, so your book is wrong. Don't trust it. Gerunds are verbs that are the main verbs in gerund clauses, which are noun clauses that can be subjects or objects, like _Leaving early is a good idea_. But _hearing the sound_ is not a subject or object, just an adverbial of circumstance, so calling it a participle is correct. Even more correct would be to call it a verb, which is what it is. _Participle_ is just another verb form, like infinitive and past tense.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, I appreciate it. I was getting very confused.

Comment: Finite verb: _They **heard** the sound; they came out of the house._ . . . Finite verb: _When they **heard** the sound, they came out of the house._ . . . Nonfinite verb (participle): _Upon **hearing** the sound, they came out of the house._ . . . Nonfinite verb (participle): _**Hearing** the sound, they came out of the house._ **Verbs** all.

Answer (score 3):

It is a participle.  You can tell this because it **qualifies** (describes) "they", the subject of the verb.  Being a participle, it is a kind of adjective:  a *verbal* adjective.  that is, it is an adjective formed from a verb base - in this case, *hear*.

Now in the following sentence, *hearing* is a so-called *gerund*.

> Hearing the sound was the most significant thing I experienced all day.

In this case hearing functions as a noun:  a *verbal* noun.  You can tell this because *hearing* is the subject of the main verb *is*.  It could be the object of a verb.

> I hate **hearing** the sound.

It is not always that easy, these are the simplest way to explain the difference between these two features.